# php setcookie, domain not properly limited in chrome but is in firefox

Tags: php, google-chrome, firefox, dns, setcookie

I'm setting a cookie in php:

```
 setcookie('testcookie[test_id]', "testvalue", (time()+(60*60*24*31)), "/", ".".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'],"1");
```

My live site domain value is like ".examplelive.com" and the test site is similar but shorter, e.g. ".example.com".

Here is the funny thing: The cookie is set fine, both on my testing server and live server. On my testing server, I can see both cookies, the cookie is duplicated!

So, for example when I navigate from my live server to my testing server, the cookies is duplicated and I can see both live and testing versions when browsing the test stie in Chrome. In FireFox, I only see one copy of the cookie in either site, which is desired result.

I have an entry in /etc/hosts on my machine to direct ".example.com" to my test site.

So, am I doing something wrong in how I'm setting cookies, or is this a quirk of Chrome?

Comment: Are they really separate domains, or is one a subdomain of the other, like `test.example.com`?

Comment: What do you mean by "the cookie is duplicated"? Are you seeing this in the console?

Comment: Yes, they are separate domains, definitely not subdomain.  By duplicates, I mean that the cookie named e.g. testcookie appears twice, once for each domain, when viewing the test site and using chrome inspector.

Comment: It sounds to me like you've simply visited both domains, so both their cookies are in the browser. What's the problem with that?

Comment: Setting a cookie in one domain has no effect on cookies with the same name in other domains. That's the whole point of making cookies domain-specific.

Comment: Haha yes it's certainly possible that I'm misunderstanding the whole context - apologies if so... but in chrome > inspect > Application > cookies > select the testexample.com domain, it lists cookies for both domains, but the converse is not true when viewing the live site. Inspecting similarly in Firefox also only showed the one cookie for both live and test domains. I was having an issue with the cookie in the test site, so wanted to understand / figure this part out. Thank you!

Comment: I see the same thing here on SO. I see cookies for `.stackoverflow.com`, `.imgur.com`, and `.scorecardresearch.com`.

Comment: Does your test site load images from the live server?

Comment: Aha! I'm not at work now to confirm but that is a very likely solution. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Barmar for pointing out the possibility of the test site loading a resource (e.g. image) from the live site. That was indeed what was happening and I'd missed it.

Interestingly, the difference in Chrome vs. FireFox in how 'inspect' shows cookies remains. The cookie from the live site shows under the test domain when 'inspect'ing cookies in Chrome, but not FireFox.